# Google Plus Posting with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I wanted to post to Google+ user stream with an extension via Javascript.  I know Google+ has no APIs yet, but I've seen this done with a PHP api.  Does anyone have pointers as to where to start implementing this? I don't need anything fancy: just ability to post into the stream.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html

here you can generate code you needed.

Comment: Hi and thanks for posting this, however, I'm looking for posting into users stream, not a general +1 that will rank up the entry.  I'm also not interested in URLs, simply a message...

Comment: Sorry:( I've misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware right now the google plus api released is only read access.You can't pull data from it

https://developers.google.com/+/api/

We will have to wait for them to release......

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that finds this - there is a Javascript plugin available

https://github.com/yipyo/google-plus-extension-jsapi

However this will only work as a browser extension because it will require access to the Google Plus page user.

I don't believe you could do it any other way and currently the API only allows read access unfortunately.